# dotnetnuke file manager replace a file

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm using DotNetNuke's file manager and the files have these hard links that DNN generates. When I delete a file and upload a file of the same name, the hard link changes.

Can I get the file to use the old URL of the deleted file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to upload the file and let DNN replace the existing file.  if you delete the file it is removed from the database, and when re-added it is assigned a new ID value, thus your links will be broken.